# Taking in multiple potential object types as a parameter

Tags: java, object, generics, parameters

In my code, I am trying to check various objects to see if they have certain values.  I am trying to find a way to be able to check all different objects with just one function.  I am new to generic classes/methods and programming in general, but imagined that the follow code would work, but it doesn't.

I test the below code by passing an object of type Lege (code variables are written in Norwegian - sorry).

```
public boolean isValid(T obj) {

    if (obj instanceof Lege) { //if we are checking a lege
        for (Lege x : leger) {
            if (x.hentNavn().toLowerCase() == obj.hentNavn().toLowerCase()) return false;
        }
    }
    else if (obj instanceof Legemiddel) { //if we are checking a legemiddel
        for (Legemiddel x : legemidler) {
            if (x.hentNavn().toLowerCase() == obj.hentNavn().toLowerCase()) return false;
        }
    }
    else if (obj instanceof Pasient) { //if we are checking a pasient
        for (Pasient x : pasienter) {
            if (x.hentNavn().toLowerCase() == obj.hentNavn().toLowerCase()) return false;
        }
    }
    else if (obj instanceof Resept) { //if we are checking a resept
        String legeNavn = obj.hentLege().navn.toLowerCase();
        String pasientNavn = obj.hentPasient().navn.toLowerCase();
        String legemiddelNavn = obj.hentLegemiddel().navn.toLowerCase();
        boolean found = false;
        boolean gyldigOverall = true;
        for (Lege a : leger) { //loop through alle leger - se om vi kan finne a match
            if (a.navn.toLowerCase() == legeNavn) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            gyldigOverall = false;
            System.out.println("Ugyldig Lege");
        }
        found = false;
        for (Pasient b : pasienter) { //loop through alle pasienter - se om vi kan finne
            if (b.navn.toLowerCase() == pasientNavn) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            gyldigOverall = false;
            System.out.println("Ugyldig Pasient");
        }
        found = false;
        for (Legemiddel c : legemidler) { //loop through alle pasienter - se om vi kan finne
            if (c.navn.toLowerCase() == legemiddelNavn) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            gyldigOverall = false;
            System.out.println("Ugyldig Legemiddel");
        }
        if (!gyldigOverall) return false; //what to output for resept
        else return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Doesn't look like generics will help here. You should pass `Object` as a parameter, or if there's a common superclass of all the classes you're checking, then that. Also, obligatory reading for beginners: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: I tried Object obj as a parameter, but then when I try to access a method of the class I sent in (ie: Pasient) then it will error - for example object.getName() I think errored because it isn't recognized as a Pasient object but just as Object?

Comment: _because it isn't recognized as a Pasient object but just as Object?_ - yes, correct. But if you know it's actually a Pasient object (if `obj instanceof Pasient` is true), then you can cast the obj to Pasient safely: `Pasient pasient = (Pasient) obj;` and then you can call the expected methods.